# How to remove repeating "toc" from the bottom of the index page in sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

Here's my `index.rst`:

```
Welcome to the documentation!
=============================

.. include:: readme.rst

.. _INTRODUCTION::
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1
   :caption: Introduction

   readme

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1
   :caption: Contents:

   gazetimation


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
```

Here what I'm getting:

[image]

How do I get rid off the repeating toc below the author section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`:hidden:` option for `toctree`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree).

> You can also give a “hidden” option to the directive, like this:
>
> ```
> .. toctree::
>     :hidden:
>
>     doc_1
>     doc_2
> ```
>
> This will still notify Sphinx of the document hierarchy, but not insert links into the document at the location of the directive – this makes sense if you intend to insert these links yourself, in a different style, or in the HTML sidebar.